# Difficulty understanding the intuition behind two-population z-test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, z-test, ab-test

I'm trying to understand how I would compare conversion rate data in an A/B test. I've read a lot of posts on this, all of which generally boil down to computing a z-score using something like

$$
z=\frac{\overline{cr_A} - \overline{cr_B}}{\sqrt{\frac{cr_A*(1-cr_A)}{N_A} + \frac{cr_B*(1-cr_B)}{N_B}}}
$$

where $cr$ represents a conversion rate. What I don't understand is the denominator. I get that it should be a standard deviation, but I'm not sure what that standard deviation is of. Assuming our treatment group is $A$, why is it not acceptable to calculate something like

$$
z=\frac{\overline{cr_A} - \overline{cr_B}}{\sqrt{\frac{cr_B*(1-cr_B)}{N_B}}}
$$

since we want to know how far $cr_B$ is from the mean of the distribution of $A$.

Comment: It is the standard deviation of the difference.  If the two groups are independent, then the variance of the difference is the sum of the variance.

Comment: @DemetriPananos got it, that makes sense. What I'm still struggling with though is why the variance of one of the groups is $\frac{cr_A*(1-cr_A)}{N_A}$. Aren't they binomial distributions, so we would expect the variance to be $N_A*cr_A*(1-cr_A)$, which is the variance of a binomial distribution?